# gpiomon from libgpiod library seem not to behave correctly

Tags: linux, gpio

I am trying to monitor GPIO events using `libgpiod` on the armbian linux.
Accourding to [pinout of my device (BananaPI Zero M2 /w H3 allwinner chip)](https://wiki.banana-pi.org/Banana_Pi_BPI-M2_ZERO)
I have pin `CON2-P18`  hooked on impulse button so I can test it.
First I'll find what line the pin is:

```
# gpiofind "CON2-P18"
gpiochip0 68
```

then I'll try to monitor it with `gpiomon` with no luck:

```
# gpiomon --rising-edge 0 68
gpiomon: error waiting for events: No such device
```

however I can confirm `gpioget` utility recognizes it and behaves properly on the button event:

```
# gpioget --bias=pull-down 0 68
0
root@bananapim2zero:~# gpioget --bias=pull-down 0 68
1
root@bananapim2zero:~# gpioget --bias=pull-down 0 68
0
```

I can also set it using `gpioset` utility:

```
# gpioset -B pull-down gpiochip0 68=0
```

I have verified the same process for monitoring `CON2-P16` and that all works fine!
The same error and behavior I get when I try to monitor pin `CON2-P18`.

To simply use another pin would be kind of troublesome for me, because I have already designed and got manufactured PCBs using forementioned pins/lines. And I would like to use `gpiomon` utility instead of endless looping on `gpioget`.

Am I doing something wrong or is the lib faulty?

`libgpiod v. 1.6.2-1`

```
# uname -a
Linux bananapim2zero 6.1.11-sunxi #23.02.2 SMP Sat Feb 18 05:52:53 UTC 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

thanks!

EDIT:

providing `strace` of
'faulty' command: `$ strace sudo gpiomon --bias=pull-down --rising-edge gpiochip0 68`:

```
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "gpiomon", "--bias=pull-down", "--rising-edge", "gpiochip0", "68"], 0xbed32684 /* 24 vars */) = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x192b000
fcntl64(0, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(1, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(2, F_GETFD)                     = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fd6000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/neon/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/v7l", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/neon/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/neon/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/neon", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/tls", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/neon/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/neon/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/neon", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/v7l/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/v7l", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/neon/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/neon/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/neon/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/neon", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/vfp/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo/vfp", 0xbea15a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24663, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 24663, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6fcf000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\364\"\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=107848, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 237700, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f74000
mprotect(0xb6f8d000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f9d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0xb6f9d000
mmap2(0xb6f9f000, 61572, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f9f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0@R\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108036, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 179236, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f48000
mprotect(0xb6f61000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f71000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0xb6f71000
mmap2(0xb6f73000, 3108, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f73000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\200\n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9800, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73908, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f35000
mprotect(0xb6f37000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f46000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xb6f46000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\320=\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=79628, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 145056, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f11000
mprotect(0xb6f24000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f33000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12000) = 0xb6f33000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\25K\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=113596, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 152152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6eeb000
mprotect(0xb6efe000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f0d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12000) = 0xb6f0d000
mmap2(0xb6f0f000, 4696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f0f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\331v\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=971712, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1040988, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6dec000
mprotect(0xb6ed6000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6ee5000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe9000) = 0xb6ee5000
mmap2(0xb6ee8000, 8796, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6ee8000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcap-ng.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0H\16\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13860, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 78068, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6dd8000
mprotect(0xb6ddb000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6dea000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0xb6dea000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\250\31\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=415588, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 479836, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6d62000
mprotect(0xb6dc7000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6dd6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x64000) = 0xb6dd6000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0000\n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9772, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73924, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6d4f000
mprotect(0xb6d51000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6d60000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xb6d60000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fcd000
set_tls(0xb6fcdbd0)                     = 0
mprotect(0xb6ee5000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6d60000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f0d000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6dd6000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6dea000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f33000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f46000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f71000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f9d000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x43f000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0xb6fd8000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6fcf000, 24663)               = 0
set_tid_address(0xb6fcd778)             = 10974
set_robust_list(0xb6fcd780, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0xb6eef66d, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xb6e13841}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0xb6eef6f1, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xb6e13841}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0xbea1655c)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", {f_type=EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=7438627, f_bfree=6853088, f_bavail=6769594, f_files=1855392, f_ffree=1745592, f_fsid={val=[2118024466, 2550696797]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOATIME}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x192b000
brk(0x194c000)                          = 0x194c000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\ttmpfs\nnodev\tbd"..., 1024) = 386
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_AS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_AS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_CORE, NULL, {rlim_cur=0, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_CPU, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_CPU, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_DATA, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_DATA, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_FSIZE, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_FSIZE, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_LOCKS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, NULL, {rlim_cur=65536*1024, rlim_max=65536*1024}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=256, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, NULL, {rlim_cur=2962, rlim_max=2962}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=2962, rlim_max=2962}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
fcntl64(0, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(1, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(2, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3041456, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6b4f000
mmap2(NULL, 2596864, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x6d000) = 0xb68d5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2329, ...}) = 0
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2329, ...}) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2329
_llseek(3, -1479, [850], SEEK_CUR)      = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1479
close(3)                                = 0
stat64("/etc/sudo.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3975, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/sudo.conf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3975, ...}) = 0
read(3, "#\n# Default /etc/sudo.conf file\n"..., 4096) = 3975
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
geteuid32()                             = 1000
access("/usr/local/bin/sudo", X_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/bin/sudo", X_OK)           = 0
stat64("/usr/bin/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=135928, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is /usr/"..., 133effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?) = 133
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
)                       = 1
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

'working' `$ sudo  strace gpiomon --bias=pull-down --rising-edge gpiochip0 15` command:

```
execve("/usr/bin/gpiomon", ["gpiomon", "--bias=pull-down", "--rising-edge", "gpiochip0", "15"], 0xbed83760 /* 16 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x17ce000
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f11000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24663, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 24663, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f0a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpiod.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\260!\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21952, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 86024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6ed4000
mprotect(0xb6ed9000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6ee8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0xb6ee8000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\331v\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=971712, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1040988, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6dd5000
mprotect(0xb6ebf000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6ece000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe9000) = 0xb6ece000
mmap2(0xb6ed1000, 8796, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6ed1000
close(3)                                = 0
set_tls(0xb6f12180)                     = 0
mprotect(0xb6ece000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6ee8000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4a1000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0xb6f13000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6f0a000, 24663)               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT TERM], NULL, 8) = 0
signalfd4(-1, [INT TERM], 8, 0)         = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3300, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x17ce000
brk(0x17ef000)                          = 0x17ef000
getdents64(4, 0x17ce1b0 /* 165 entries */, 32768) = 4896
getdents64(4, 0x17ce1b0 /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/gpiochip0", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
lstat64("/dev/gpiochip0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfe, 0), ...}) = 0
stat64("/dev/gpiochip0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfe, 0), ...}) = 0
access("/sys/bus/gpio/devices/gpiochip0/dev", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/gpio/devices/gpiochip0/dev", O_RDONLY) = 5
read(5, "254:0\n", 15)                  = 6
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(4, GPIO_GET_CHIPINFO_IOCTL, 0xbee98018) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/gpiochip1", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
lstat64("/dev/gpiochip1", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfe, 0x1), ...}) = 0
stat64("/dev/gpiochip1", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfe, 0x1), ...}) = 0
access("/sys/bus/gpio/devices/gpiochip1/dev", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/gpio/devices/gpiochip1/dev", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "254:1\n", 15)                  = 6
close(6)                                = 0
ioctl(5, GPIO_GET_CHIPINFO_IOCTL, 0xbee98018) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/gpiochip0", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
lstat64("/dev/gpiochip0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfe, 0), ...}) = 0
stat64("/dev/gpiochip0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfe, 0), ...}) = 0
access("/sys/bus/gpio/devices/gpiochip0/dev", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/gpio/devices/gpiochip0/dev", O_RDONLY) = 5
read(5, "254:0\n", 15)                  = 6
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(4, GPIO_GET_CHIPINFO_IOCTL, 0xbee98058) = 0
ioctl(4, GPIO_GET_LINEINFO_IOCTL, 0xbee9807c) = 0
ioctl(4, GPIO_GET_LINEEVENT_IOCTL, 0xbee9809c) = 0
ioctl(4, GPIO_GET_LINEINFO_IOCTL, 0xbee9803c) = 0
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
read(5, "\233\\D\336\201\10\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 16
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "event:  RISING EDGE offset: 15 t"..., 63event:  RISING EDGE offset: 15 timestamp: [    9353.872825499]
) = 63
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
read(5, "\213\273\312\6\203\10\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 16
write(1, "event:  RISING EDGE offset: 15 t"..., 63event:  RISING EDGE offset: 15 timestamp: [    9358.847687563]
) = 63
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, 10000^C) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
strace: Process 10962 detached
```

Comment: unlikely to be the library's fault, nor yours. It's quite possible that the pins you're trying to observe simply aren't connected to an interrupt-generating unit. (Or that the kernel for technical reason doesn't support that. Or it was simply never implemented.) You'll have to read the datasheet of your computer's SoC to figure out whether this is a hardware limitation or caused by your operating system simply never implemented that.

Comment: well, why would `gpioget` work properly then?

Comment: because that just reads the pin; it doesn't require interrupts to be working.

Comment: no clue how that works. do you know of some way to verify this assumption? thanks

Comment: sure, check what system call fails specifically when you `gpiomon` fails (It's probably an `epoll` or `select` call), and then debug down into the kernel why it does.

Comment: that would definitely do the trick, but also looking at those GPIO pin names: those that I see working with `gpiomon` contain *EINT* that can stand for 'interruption' just by little stretch and proves you righ. oh well...

Comment: don't fret too much; polling a GPIO pin is not too bad, when you can accept a couple millisecond of delay; just `sleep` in between checking the state. (hint: most CPU time would go into starting `gpioget`, so maybe write your own python script to check the state periodically, or use `gpioset`'s [interactive mode](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/README) to query states. If you really need low-latency / power-saving interrupt-based operation, also not too bad a hardware modification: with two diodes you can make `0 68` have effect on an interrupt-enabled pin as

Comment: well, and then when you see an interrupt (i.e. when gpiomon returns), you just check the state of 0 68 and know which one of the actual inputs fired.

Comment: yeeah, thanks for suggestions! would be intersting with those two diodes, I guess I'll either wont solder pin 68 and wire trhe track to the interrupted one or implement polling on an old sysfs way, just to save time starting gpioget as you say..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the Allwinner_H3_Datasheet Section 3.3 ~pg80 (via link at the bottom of the [Banana Pi page](https://wiki.banana-pi.org/Banana_Pi_BPI-M2_ZERO), only the `EINT` pins support interrupt.

According to the same Banana Pi page, `CON2-P128` corresponds to `PC4` on the `H3`, so not one of the `PA` or `PG` `EINT` pins and so no interrupt support.

Nothing the software, be it the kernel GPIO driver or `libgpiod`, can do to make that line provide interrupts.  Your only options are to poll that line or switch to one of the `EINT` pins.

Btw, one of  comments suggested using `libgpiod v2` `gpioset`'s interactive mode to get the line value as a performance optimization.  Speaking as the author of that mode, that will not work - `gpioset` will hold the line output, and the value the `get` returns is the value the line is currently being set to (in case you toggle it a few times and lose track).  So not what you want.  General rule - don't use `gpioset` on input lines being driven externally - that can let the magic smoke out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `libgpiod`. Can you run `gpiomon` over `strace` and make sure that there's no file descriptor raising any poll events? If there's none, then there's no interrupt being reported by the kernel which means that either the driver is behaving incorrectly (unlikely) or your HW is not generating those interrupts (likely).

What is the driver you're using? Is your board using upstream device-tree?

Bart

Comment: I have added strace to the question. not sure how to read it tho.. there are some poll evts, but i don't know how to shield it from something else rising them...